# Zero padding for Savitzgy Golay filter not working for C++ numerical recipe

Tags: c++, filtering, padding, convolution

My problem is straight forward: 
I want to smooth some data using the Savitzgy Golay filter. I use C++. 
The code is taken from the book [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSaT1.png) and can be split into two parts:

1. Calculate the Savitzgy Golay coefficients and store them in a vector C.
2. Smooth the signal data S by convoluting it with C.

The problem is the boundaries. Since the signal S is not periodic, boundary effects have to be taken into consideration. This is done with so-called 0-padding, meaning that some extra 0s are added to the signal at the end. The procedure is described exactly in chapter 13.1.1 of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSaT1.png).

However, I cannot find a complete example of this procedure, and my own implementation does not seem to work, although I can absolutely not understand why. Below is a well-commented example. Can somebody spot what is going wrong at the boundaries?

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSaT1.png) William H., et al. "Numerical recipes: the art of scientific
>   computing." (1987)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "./numerical_recipes/other/nr.h"
#include "./numerical_recipes/recipes/savgol.cpp"
#include "./numerical_recipes/recipes/lubksb.cpp"
#include "./numerical_recipes/recipes/ludcmp.cpp"
#include "./numerical_recipes/recipes/convlv.cpp"
#include "./numerical_recipes/recipes/realft.cpp"
#include "./numerical_recipes/recipes/four1.cpp"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // set savgol parameters
    int nl = 6;  // left window length
    int nr = 6;  // right window length 
    int m  = 3;  // order of interpolation polynomial

    // calculate savitzgy golay coefficients
    int np=nl+nr+1;         // number of coefficients
    Vec_DP coefs(np);       // vector that stores the coefficients
    NR::savgol(coefs,np,nl,nr,0,m); // calculate the coefficients

    // as example input data, generate sinh datapoints between -1 and 1
    int nvals = int(pow(2,7))-nl; // number of datapoints to analyze (equal to 2^7 including zero-padding)
    Vec_DP args(nvals); // stores arguments
    Vec_DP vals(nvals); // stores signal
    double next_arg; // help variable 
    for(int i = 0; i < nvals; i++)
    {   
        next_arg = i*2./(nvals-1)-1;    // next argument 
        args[i] = next_arg;             // store argument point
        vals[i] = sinh(next_arg);        // evaluate next value 
    }

    // for zero padding, we have to add nl datapoints to the right. The signal is then of length 2^7. 
    // see also chapter 13.1.1 in [1]
    // [1] Press, William H., et al. "Numerical recipes: the art of scientific computing." (1987)
    Vec_DP input_signal(int(pow(2,7))); // create vector of length 2^7
    for(int i = 0; i < nvals; i++) input_signal[i] = vals[i]; // overwrite with actual signal 
    for(int i = nvals; i < int(pow(2,7)); i++) input_signal[i] = 0.0; // add zeros for zero-patting

    // perfrom the convolution 
    Vec_DP ans(int(pow(2,7)));  // stores the smoothed signal 
    NR::convlv(input_signal,coefs,1,ans); // smoothen the data 

    // write data to the output for visual inspection 
    string filename = "test.csv"; // output filename
    string write_line;  
    ofstream wto(filename,ios::app);
    for(int i = 0; i < nvals; i++) // write result to output, drop the values from 0-padding
    {
        write_line = to_string(args[i])+", "+to_string(vals[i])+= ", "+to_string(ans[i]); 
        wto << write_line << endl;
    }
    wto.close();

    return 0; 
}
```

Here is a visualization of the output. We can clearly see that the fit fails at the boundaries, although zero-padding was taken into consideration.

[image]

Comment: Try plotting your signal with the zero added padding, the resulting signal is not continuous at the boundaries and that generates the artifacts (polynomials aren't good at fitting non continuous functions).

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is the boundaries. Since the signal S is not periodic, boundary effects have to be taken into consideration. This is done with so-called 0-padding, meaning that some extra 0s are added to the signal at the end. The procedure is described exactly in chapter 13.1.1 of 1.

In my edition of Numerical Recipies, Chapter 13 is "Fourier and spectral applications". While zero-padding the signal is perfectly fine for the Fourier Transform, it's not a good idea for Savitzky-Golay.

I see a couple of ways to apply Savitzky-Golay smoothing at signal boundaries:

1. Exclude the missing bits of the signal from convolution. Set the coefficients corresponding to the missing bits to zero and re-normalize the rest of them to sum to 1.
2. Compute a special Savitzky-Golay kernel for each signal point with an incomplete neighborhood. That's actually not hard to do. Conceptually, convolving with a Savitzky-Golay kernel is equivalent to fitting a polynomial to a neighborhood of a signal point and then taking that signal point from the polynomial. Nothing prevents you from having a one-sided or an asymmetric neighborhood. Building a Savitzky-Golay kernel for an arbitrary neighborhood is a matter of fitting a polynomial to a signal where the value at origin is 1 and zero everywhere else. The origin doesn't have to be at the center of a neighborhood. The Savitzky-Golay kernel coefficients are then the values of the fitted polynomial function at the corresponding signal points.

Comment: It is strange to me that the zero-padding does not work though. Also, the book does not mention any problems at the boundary. Anyway, I have solved now the problem by fitting locally a polynomial, similar to your suggestion nr 2. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem now similar to @Tulon's 2. suggestion. Specifically, I take care of the left and right boundary by fitting there an extra polynomial on both sides. This is motivated by the implementation of the Savitzgy Golay filter in the Scipy.signal library for Python.